# What is a self-delimiting program?

Tags: turing-machines, reference-request

I came across the term self-delimiting program, referring to the paper "Laws of information (nongrowth) and aspects of the foundation of probability theory" by Levin, 1974.

Unfortunately this paper is not available afaik, and I couldn't find any definition anywhere. What is the definition? or what is a resource stating the definition and explaining the idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a specific program could be self-delimiting, in this context what we usually mean is a *self-delimiting encoding of programs*. An encoding of programs is *self-delimiting* if it forms a *prefix code*, that is, no program is a prefix of another program. Intuitively, programs are self-delimiting, so there is no ambiguity in where a program ends.

Why do we care? Consider the chain rule in Kolmogorov complexity, which expresses the idea that if there are short programs that generate $x$ and $y$, then there is a short program that generates the concatenation $xy$. If programs are self-delimiting, then a program for generating $xy$ could look as follows:

- Run the following two programs in sequence.
- Program for generating $x$.
- Program for generating $y$.

Denoting the Kolmogorov complexity of a string $w$ by $C(w)$, this shows that $$ C(xy) \leq C(x) + C(y) + O(1). $$
(The $O(1)$ takes care of the first bit.)

In contrast, if programs are not self-delimiting, then it is impossible to tell where the program for generating $x$ ends. Therefore the chain rule for non-self-delimiting Kolmogorov complexity takes the more complicated form $$ K(xy) \leq K(x) + K(y) + O(\log K(x) + 1), $$
where $O(\log K(x))$ is needed to delimit the first program.

Self-delimiting programs are also useful for defining the *universal distribution*, which is a distribution on programs useful for understanding average-case complexity. The probability that the program $P$ comes up is $2^{-|P|}$. Since the valid programs form a prefix code, Kraft's inequality states that $\sum_P 2^{-|P|} \leq 1$, so this is a (sub-)probability distribution.

So far the advantages of prefix-free Kolmogorov complexity. The disadvantage is that whereas $K(w) \leq |w|$, this no longer holds for $C(w)$; instead we only have $C(w) \leq |w| + O(\log |w|+1)$.

You can read a lot more on these issues in the excellent monograph of Li and Vitanyi on Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: Aren't C and K switched in the second-to-last paragraph?

Comment: Possibly. I find it very confusing.

Comment: On reflection, it seems correct.

Comment: If we have a self-delimiting code of programs, can't we always get a free improvement (i.e. without increasing the length of any programs), by getting rid of the "Run the following two programs in sequence."? We can just have our universal turing machine always execute two programs in order if they are written after eachother, since there doesn't seem to be any other reasonable way to deal with two programs written directly after each other. Hence, we can get the inequality to be $C(xy) \leq C(x) + C(y)$.

Comment: Not really. When you join two such programs, you could now have up to four programs.